# find specific files and copy to new folder

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find all txt files in mutiple directories and use the contents of `file` to match each txt file and copy them to a new directory (all). Not every directory will have a match
and there are more then txt files inside each, but those are not needed. The below executes but no files are copied. Thank you :).

**dir**

```
123456789000
  123456789000_00a.txt
  123456789000_00b.txt
  123456789000_04a.txt
  123456789000_04b.txt
  123456789000_05a.txt
  123456789000_05b.txt
123456789111
  123456789111_00a.txt
  123456789111_00b.txt
123456789222
  123456789222_00a.txt
  123456789222_00b.txt
```

**file**

```
123456789000_00
123456789000_04
123456789111_00
```

**desired all**

```
123456789000_00a.txt
123456789000_00b.txt
123456789000_04a.txt
123456789000_04b.txt
123456789111_00a.txt
123456789111_00b.txt
```

**bash**

```
for a in *; do  # loop and read into a
  [ -d "$a" ] || continue # ensure a is directory
    cd "$a" ## descend into each $a
     find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} ${dest} \; # find txt file in directory and use file to match
    cd ..  ## go one directory back
done  <file  ## close loop
```

Comment: Wouldn't `123456789111_00a.txt` and `123456789111_00b.txt` also be in your desired output since `123456789111_00` is in your input file?

Comment: Yes they would, sorry for the oversight, I will correct. Thaank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code doesn't actually use the content of `file` at all, it's looping over a glob (presumably matching your directories), changing into each directory and attempting to grab all txt files. You also have a syntax error in `$(dest}` which may be why nothing gets copied.

This is closer to what you described:

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
  find -type f -name "${line}*txt" -exec cp {} "${dest}" \; 
done < file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... I corrected the syntax error as well. :).